# "The paper lies" vs. "The paper is lied"

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar, verbs

> - 1- The paper ***lies*** before me on the desk.
> - 2- The paper is ***lied*** before me on the desk.

What is the difference between these two sentences in using the two forms of the verbs?

Second, when could we use "verbs" in active form after things such as papers or things that can't move?

Comment: The difference is this: the first sentence is grammatical, the second is not. Use the progressive form (*is lying*) to make #2 grammatical.

Comment: Ok, when we could use verbs after things can't move? @Robusto

Comment: When there is an outside force. "The paper *flew* through the air." Presumably due to the wind or if someone threw it.

Answer (score 3):

In the second pattern, the subject complement would be the past participle of a transitive verb.

> Place the paper on the table.
>
> The paper is placed on the table.
>
> Lay <sup>transitive</sup> the paper on the table.

The past participle of **to lay** is **laid**.

> The paper is|was laid on the table.

Someone **lays** <sup>present</sup>  the paper on the desk each morning.

Someone **laid** <sup>past</sup> the paper on the desk.

Someone **has laid** <sup>present perfect</sup> the paper on the desk.

Answer (score 1):

> The paper *lies* before me on the desk.
>
> The paper *is lying* before me on the desk.

These forms are correct.

Theoretically you could use a passive ("The desk is *lain* on by the paper") but this would sound a bit weird.

There are three verbs that are easily confused:

- To **lie** (intransitive) To tell a falsehood. (Past: *lied*, past participle: *lied*)
- To **lie** (intransitive) To recline, or to be positioned. (Past: *lay*, past participle: *lain*)
- To **lay** (transitive) To put. (Past: *laid*, past participle: *laid*)

Hence if you used the verb "*lay*" instead, you could say:

> The paper was **laid** on the desk.